# Can you treat the <i> element like any other element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the height/width of my menu bars but have not had any success using the `<i>` element which it's nested within. Using the `<i>` element works to change the color but, when I try to change width and height, it doesn't work.

Tried Css:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) 
{.module>.fa-bars  {width: 
20px !important; height: 
20px! important;}}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{.fa-bars  {width: 
20px !important; height: 
20px! important;}}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{.fa-bars  {width: 
20px height: 
20px!}}

@media (max-width: 768px) 
{.fa-bars a {width: 
20px height: 
20px!}}
```

Html:

```
<div class="module widget- 
handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs"><i 
class="fa fa-bars"></i>
```

Comment: Give font-size to i tag or class fa fa-bars. @Amg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<i>` element is similar to a `<span>` in which it is an [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) element. Whereas something like a `<div>` for example is a a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) type element.

You cannot change the width and height of `inline` elements, but you can change how they display with `display:block` (or `inline-block` if that suits your needs) to overwrite the default `display:inline`. You can then treat it as you would a `<div>`

Comment: Worth adding that as OP is using font awesome, just changing the width and height won't affect the icon size itself, as that is based on font size.

Comment: @ButchMonkey yes, it does seem that you need to change display before you can treat it as a div. Only after can you alter font size, or anything else it seems. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome Icons are inside a font. So there are two ways.

1. You can set their size with font-size.
2. Font Awesome includes a set of classes to increase the icons relative to their container. fa-lg (33% increase) or fa-2x, fa-3x, fa-4x, or fa-5x

Comment: Thanks. So what would the syntax be? `fa-bars2x. Using font-size doesn't work for me.

Comment: Refer this links: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/sizing-icons,  http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/w3css/w3css_icons.asp.html @Amg

Comment: <div class="module widget- 
handle mobile-toggle right 
visible-sm visible-xs"><i 
class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i> @Amg

Comment: Please see comment to @ButchMonkey. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add Css -

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.module i {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

}

Comment: But wouldn't that change all i elements, if it worked? Just want to change `fa-bars`

Comment: That's why i have taken a class i.e. .module which only takes i element which is in module class.